# Pydantic Dataclasses with SqlAlchemy Rasies UnmappedInstanceError

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pydantic

### Problem

When using pydantic's dataclass class sqlalchemy mapper give an `UnmappedInstanceError`.

### Implementation

```py
# Create a simple user pydantic dataclass
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class User:
    full_name: str
    email: str

# Map sqlalchemy to the model above
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
import model

metadata = sa.MetaData()

user = sa.Table(
    'user', metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    sa.Column("full_name", sa.String(), nullable=True),
)

user_mapper = mapper(model.User, user)

# Create Sqlalchemy session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(database_uri)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# adding user from above into the session
user = User(full_name='Hey You', email='who@me.com')
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

### Error

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'User' is mapped, but this instance lacks instrumentation.  This occurs when the instance is created before sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(User) was called.

What in pydantic's dataclass causes this issue? Using python's base Dataclass doesn't cause an issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution or reason for this?

Comment: No, I ended up using dataclasses instead. You might want to look into the new SQLAlchemy declarative mapping. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#orm-declarative-dataclasses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue between Pydantic and SQLAlchemy that won't be fixed. This [github issue](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1089) has more details.

From the creator of Pydantic:

> Best to use ORM mode.
>
> I have no personal interest in ORMs or supporting them - long term they're a mistake, you'd do much better to just write SQL.
>
> However if there's some easy way to support mapper that required a relatively small change to pydantic, I'd be happy to review a PR.
>
> -- samuelcolvin

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try and fix this tomorrow, wish me luck. I am not 100% clear precisely where the issue is currently, but have posted on this issue https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1089 and have a minimal test case in this repo https://github.com/DomWeldon/pydantic-dataclasses-sqlalchemy

Comment: Any thoughts or comments appreciated

Comment: This is going from the opposite direction but might provide some help. https://github.com/tiangolo/pydantic-sqlalchemy

Comment: Thanks - this was identified as a bug in pydantic and I think is resolved in the latest version - https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/3043

Comment: super cool! thank you